# Console problem runing npm install on a Udemy project

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I'm having this error in the console while I'm trying to do mpn install.
It's a project from Udemy.
How can I solve this issue?
I'm running:

Angular CLI: 13.3.6

Node: 17.4.0

Package Manager: npm 8.3.1

OS: win32 x64

```
PS C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world> npm install

npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'karma@1.7.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.10 || 0.12 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v17.4.0', npm: '8.3.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'karma-cli@1.0.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.10 || 0.12 || 4 || 5 || 6'
},
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v17.4.0', npm: '8.3.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated xmldom@0.1.31: Deprecated due to CVE-2021-21366 resolved in 0.5.0
npm WARN deprecated json3@3.3.2: Please use the native JSON object instead of JSON 3
npm WARN deprecated extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2: Deprecated. Please use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@2.0.5: This version has been deprecated
in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and
security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated boom@2.10.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support
is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated sntp@1.0.9: This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support
is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@2.30.1: out of support
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@4.2.1: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.81.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated hawk@3.1.3: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated @angular/http@4.4.7: Package no longer supported.
Use @angular/common instead, see https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp
npm WARN deprecated svgo@0.7.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated log4js@0.6.38: 0.x is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because
of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Reinhard\\Downloads\\hello-world\\hello-world\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.4.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python",
you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:306:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Reinhard\\Downloads\\hello-world\\hello-world\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Reinhard\Downloads\hello-world\hello-world\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Reinhard\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-27T15_38_32_608Z-debug-0.log
```

This is my console. can someone help me because the teacher Mosh Hamedani don't give any advice on how to solve this problem.

And a advice dont but his curses!!!

Comment: Cab yu add the yur package.json

Comment: This seems like a really old project (about 5 years old?). You can try to downgrade NodeJs to an LTS 8 version.. ?

Comment: The problem is that the project is asking for an older version on node, you have 17.4.0 and ask for a maximun of 6. if you're using mac you can use <https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm> that can run multiple node versions at the same time or windows <https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows> and install the corresponding version

Comment: @Samba y can not add package.json

Comment: @MikeOne yes yes I know but its the curse that I took from Udemy

Comment: @FlorenciaCames I know and I tried but nothing happens